How to use Home and End keys in `less` command
In most Linuxes I've used, when using the less command the Home and End keys do nothing. But I've seen versions where they take you to the start / end of the file you are viewing.
Is there a setting I can put in the LESS global variable in .bashrc that would achieve that ?
I've searched through man less without success.

Which terminal emulator are you using or have used? They (just as physical terminals didn't) do not always agree on which sequences these keys should generate, and not all programs recognize all variants (especially if $TERM happens to be wrong).

It may depend on how your terminal (terminal emulator) encodes Home and End. The point is there is just a single stream of bytes coming from your terminal to less (or to any program designed to use the terminal). While b is sent as one-byte b and Ctrl+n is sent as one byte we denote ^N, the backspace may be sent as ^H or ^? and e.g. Home is encoded as a sequence. The sequence may be ^[[1~ or something else. It may be less understands one, not the other. In a shell, what do you see upon Ctrl+V, Home ? What upon Ctrl+V, End ?

Konsole in KDE, bash, TERM=xterm-color, ^[[H and ^[[F

Start less and hit h - reveals a load of key to play with, among those < and > for "home" and "end" (of file). I'd say those as are just as easy as the Home and End -keys.

Absolutely. But harder to remember. And also requires the use of the Shift key...
